ClassCastException with AppClassLoader and URLClassLoader in OpenJDK 17
I need to migrate our legacy application from java8 to java17. While running the application, I encountered the following exception with OpenJDK 17. This worked fine with Java 8, but the new class loader mechanism under the module system is causing issues. What should be the solution for this?
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader cannot be cast to class java.net.URLClassLoader (jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader and java.net.URLClassLoader are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
my java -version
openjdk version "17.0.11" 2024-04-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-17.0.11+9 (build 17.0.11+9)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-17.0.11+9 (build 17.0.11+9, mixed mode, sharing)
sharing few code snippets here: 
I am stuck for so many days, nowhere getting any solutions. Please guide me. Thanks in advance!
[I have done by implementing reflection but didn't work out, sharing the tried code:(https://i.sstatic.net/2fFqbIEM.png)
I need the solution to work in Java17?

This question is similar to: Java 9, compatability issue with ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Yes, this is different because I need the resolution for Java17 and after java11 there are so many changes happened in Java17 classloading mechanism. I already tried with custom classloader, it is dynamically adding into classpath and solving the class cast exception, but it is not loading all the classes from the jar files as it is calling a class from another jar file. and then it is giving me NoClassDefFoundError.
Request you to please give me suggestions to dynamically load all the classes from the jarfiles in java17?

There are no relevant changes between Java 11 and Java 17. If you tried to switch to Java 11 instead of Java 17, you’d have exactly the same problem, as the relevant changes happened in Java 9 already. Same problem, same solutions. Follow the provided link for solutions.
